# Square CSP Policy needs a quick update

Tags: square-connect

> Loading failed for the  with source
>   “blob:https://connect.squareup.com/2d9347c7-e067-4ca1-9aaf-7ce2c40aec44”.
>   frame.html:1
>
> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at
>   blob:https://connect.squareup.com/2d9347c7-e067-4ca1-9aaf-7ce2c40aec44
>   (“script-src 'unsafe-inline' https://browser.sentry-cdn.com”).

When will the Square developers please update their CSP policy and [address other pending issues](https://github.com/square/connect-api-specification/issues/)?

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Could you please report this via our Developer email support channel so we can help you out better: https://squareup.com/help/us/en/contact?panel=BF53A9C8EF68 feel free to reference this question as well.

Comment: @sjosey Thanks filled it out.